# NatTable flickers repeatedly on cell click and on scroll activity

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, nattable

I'm using a NatTable in an eclipse rcp based application. Whenever i click a cell or scroll the nattable flickers(may be on paint or redraw) repeatedly
Is there a way to avoid this behavior?

Comment: If you are using some custom components, like custom cell painters, filters or something else, and those do time consuming operations, it might affect the nattable performance, otherwise it should work without any problem, even if you are not using SWT.DOUBLE_BUFFERED flag.

Comment: Im using a custom filtering and a custom sorting. My NatTable implementation is also fed with large data most of the times.Thanks for the info @AlexanderGavrilov

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the *Class NatTable*  i could find that **SWT.DOUBLE_BUFFERED** being used as one of the default style options.

On adding **SWT.DOUBLE_BUFFERED** as a style option in my constructor,

```
NatTable natTable = new NatTable(parentComposite, SWT.DOUBLE_BUFFERED);
```

i could find that the flickering is reduced.